# SAS Proc Append Column format change

Tags: sas, netezza

I want to upload a table to Netezza SQL server. However, within my table I have 1 column which is of character format with len=20. However, in Netezza, I want this column to be in BIGINT format. Can I convert this specific column in proc append from Char to BigInt when appending the table to the Netezza table?

Comment: Did you try the DBTYPE= dataset option? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

#### No, not IN proc append

In `proc append` you can rename or drop columns

```
proc append 
    base=NTZ_LIB.MY_TABLE 
    data=WORK.MY_TABLE (rename=(oldName=newName) drop=notNeeded);
run;
```

but you cannot convert data.

#### But you can use a view

One way to create a view is in a data step with a `view` option

```
data WORK.MY_VIEW / view = WORK.MY_VIEW;
    set WORK.MY_DATA;
    converted = input(toConvert, 20.);
    drop toConvert;
    rename converted=toConvert;
run;
```

*You might need to change "informat" `20.` in function of content of your text field.*

The creation of this view does not read `WORK.MY_TABLE`,
it just defines what will be done when you read `WORK.MY_VIEW`.

Next you can just append the result to your Netezza table

```
proc append 
    base=NTZ_LIB.MY_TABLE 
    data=WORK.MY_VIEW;
run;
```

and technically, you convert the data while appending it.